# Тени при помощи теневых объемов (shadow volumes)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, шейдеры

Похоже, я зашел в тупик. Понемногу разбираюсь с программированием графики, решил попробовать реализовать тени альтернативным shadow-mapping'у способом, а именно при помощи техники shadow volumes (еще ее называют stencil shadows). Сейчас я опишу как я понял алгоритм, вероятно в моем понимании есть ошибка, из-за которой я не могу понять **то самое**, из-за чего я это пишу:

- Для каждого источника света, у объекта определяются силуэтные ребра. Это такие ребра, которые находятся на стыке двух полигонов (один направлен к источнику света, другой нет)
- Эти ребра вытягиваются от источника света вдаль (желательно в бесконечность). Само вытягивание можно произвести прибавлением к точкам ребер вектора идущего от источника к каждой точке помноженного на какое-то значение.
- После добавления вытянутых вершин ребер, для каждого ребра по этим вершинам строится грань, и в итоге все это образует некий конусообразный объем (так же для корректной работы следует еще добавить "крышки" в конце и в начале этого объема)
- Затем происходит отрисовка этих конусов (то есть объемов) в буфер глубины и трафарета. Причем в начале рисуются пиксели лицевых полигонов, прошедших z-тест (в этот момент в stencil буфере значения увеличивается на единицу) а затем рисуются пиксели не лицевых полигонов, опять же прошедших z-тест (и на этот раз значения в stencil буфере уменьшаются). В итоге в stencil буфере остается область где значения stencil буфера остались единицами, там то и будет тень
- Когда происходит отрисовка, то выполняется так же и тест трафарета, и отрисовка происходит только в тех месах где stencil-буфер равен нулю (то есть рисуется сцена, но области тени игнорируются)
- Затем, чтобы области с тенями не были полностью черными можно отдельным проходом отрендерить фоновый цвет, наложив его на результат предыдущего прохода (используя blending)

**Вопросы:**

Если мое описание алгоритма верно, то как при всем этом добиться эффекта наложения теней разных источников друг на друга? Например, если источников света будет несколько, и тень от одного будет перекрывать тень от другого, то в этом месте тень должна становиться еще темнее, но если следовать описанному выше алгоритму - так происходить не будет (поскольку область в stencil буфере в результате будет одна) На различных видео с демонстрацией работы этого алгоритма, я натыкался на ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ эффект (например здесь - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqyXT6nsxCQ), то есть тени от разных источников накладываются и темнеют, **но как?**

Так же есть вопрос с засветлением затененных областей другими источниками света. То есть тень должна закрывать свет только того источника, который ее породил, но этот алгоритм такого будто бы не подразумевает. В то же время, опять же, есть видео где подобное поведение реализовано - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69xKosYal-Y

На практике я остановился на построении теневого объема, но перед тем как я продолжу, мне бы просто хотелось понять в теории - как, следуя этому этому алгоритму, можно добиться такого результата как на видео? Что именно я упускаю в понимании этого подхода? Буду рад подробному пояснению.

Comment: В таких проектах нужно поддерживать связь со специалистом области. В данном случаи вам нужен художник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как было правильно замечено, в предложенном варианте добиться корректной отрисовки освещения от нескольких источников не получится. В stencil буфере будет содержаться маска, определяющая, находится ли данный пиксель в тени или нет. Соответственно для расчёта  освещенности от нескольких источников придется собирать данные о вкладе каждого из этих источников.

Это можно сделать, производя отрисовку в несколько проходов. Например, на каждом проходе производить действия по построению и отрисовке shadow volumes для одного источника освещения, но в конце рисовать геометрию не в экранный буфер, а аддитивно в карту освещенности. Тогда на выходе получится карта освещенности, где значение 0 соответствует ambient освещенности (т.е. пиксель не освещается ни одним источником света), а все значения выше нуля показывают, насколько хорошо этот пиксель освещается от источников света. С использованием этой карты освещенности в конце рисуется вся сцена.

Тут можно заметить, что добавление новых источников освещения требует увеличения количества проходов, и что при построении карты освещенности на каждом проходе можно учитывать расстояние до соответствующего источника света для получения более реалистичного результата. Также вместо карты освещенности можно аддитивно рисовать сразу в экранный буфер.

Comment: Насчет "аддитивной в карты освещенности", правильно ли я понял, что нужно будет рендерить в эту карту всю геометрию столько раз, сколько есть источников света, и при этом результат нового рендера должен накладываться на результат предыдущих? Но даже если так.. допустим на этой карте где-то были нули (дырка), а после рендера для другого источника эту дырку закрыло.. и что это дает? В этом месте ведь должно быть некое затемнение а не просто закрытие дырки?

Comment: @AlexNem Допустим есть два источника света - один с интенсивностью 0.1, а другой с 0.2. После первого прохода места, освещенные первым источником будут иметь значение 0.1, не освещенные - 0.0. После второго прохода места, освещенные только первым источником, будут по-прежнему иметь значение 0.1, освещенные только вторым источником - 0.2, освещенные обоими - 0.3, не освещенные - 0.0. В конце рисуем каждый пиксель с рассчитанной освещенностью, добавляя к ней некоторое константное значение для ambient освещенности (допустим 0.04)

Comment: А, то есть получается что шейдеру, для отрисовки геометрии (если допустим, рисуем аддитивно прямо в буфер), нужно в каждом проходе передавать только какой-то один источник, а само сложение освещенности источников будет происходить уже не в шейдере, а при наложении результатов рендеринга с проходов?

Comment: @AlexNem именно так

Comment: Кажется понял. Но тогда возникает вопрос - насколько данный подход оптимален (в плане производительности), и можно ли (а самое главное - есть ли смысл) как-то пытаться скомбинировать данный подход с отложенным освещением (deferred lighting)?

Comment: @AlexNem Наверное не особо оптимален + налагает ограничение на количество источников освещения. Однако подобный подход использовался [например в DOOM3](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/renderer.php). Всякие deferred  * техники по сути позволяют получить прирост производительности за счет кэширования результатов промежуточных вычислений. Вот если рисовать сразу в экранный буфер, то геометрию с текстурами можно отрисовать один раз.

Comment: Хм, то есть можно в G-буфер один раз отрендерить геометрию (фрагменты будут содержать начальный цвет, положения и нормали) а затем уже, проходясь по каждому источнику, в отдельных проходах, освещать и затенять эту самую геометрию, после чего все складывать? Благодарю, похоже истинный путь найден. Спасибо